# Basic Knowledge of SharePoint as a Front-End Developer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, front-end

I'm working on Sharepoint as Front-end Developer for now 4 years but now I feel I didn't have basic knowledge about this technology. Below are some questions in my mind and your input is really appreciated:

1. What is Sharepoint?
2. Why we use Sharepoint?
3. In which language we can code in Sharepoint?
4. What is the role of Front-End Developer in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer to your question. The simple answer is in its name "Share" + "Point".

A place where people can Share information. Where people are looking for and generating information.

There are variuos threads asked about the same question, maybe it will help you:

1. [What exactly is SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35958/what-exactly-is-sharepoint)
2. [What is SharePoint all about?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/what-is-sharepoint-all-about)
3. [What is SharePoint? Explaining to the business person](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36/what-is-sharepoint-explaining-to-the-business-layperson).

For Front end development you can use variuos languages for coding like:

1. C#
2. Javascript(jQuery, Angular, react, etc.) : REST services, SPServices, JSOM, etc.
3. HTML5 and CSS3 for custom solutions and dashboards.

**Source**: [Skills Every SharePoint Developer Needs](https://phoenixts.com/blog/10-skills-every-sharepoint-developer-needs/).

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already worked for 4 years as a front end developer for SharePoint , let me answer to you in a way it feels relevant.

1.**Which technologies can be used to code in SharePoint ?**

So as a front end developer you can use technologies like HTML, CSS, and JS, as well as common web toolkits/frameworks and technologies (text editors/IDEs, jQuery, AJAX, web servers; you get the drift).

2.**What exactly SharePoint is and why is it used?**

Sharepoint is a web application platform developed by Microsoft. Though you’ll find a wide array of explanations as to what Sharepoint is. It’s most often used as an intranet site for businesses of all shapes and sizes, offering a range of features:

1. Document management and collaboration
2. Company- or group-wide wiki pages
3. Large content libraries
4. Sub-sites and communities within an organization
5. Extensive built-in search functionality
6. Individual personal profile pages and social networking capabilities.

3.**What is SharePoint based on ?**

Sharepoint runs on the Microsoft stack and this stack contains following components namely:

1. Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (64-bit)
2. ASP.NET (3.5, to be exact)
3. IIS (7.0 or greater)
4. Microsoft SQL Server 2008